# Matching part before and after underscore of filename

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match parts before and after an underscore `_` in these filenames, but also the file without the underscore, e.g.:

```
test.jpg
test_1.jpg
test_2.jpg
```

I can match parts before and after using: `^(\w+)_(\d+).*$` - but this does not match `test.jpg`.

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the `_` optional using `?` quantifier

```
^(\w+)(?:_(\d+))?.*$
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/mD0yI4/1)

**Changes made**

- `(?:_(\d+))?` The quantifier `?` matches ***zero or one*** occurence of the previous regex